# Backing up Xampp databases before reinstalling Windows

Tags: xampp

Before reinstalling Windows I'd like to make sure I'll be able to retrieve my Xampp databases once Xampp reinstalled. If I simply copy the xampp > mysql > data folder somewhere and paste it back in the new Xampp install, will it work?

If not, why?

Comment: See this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294830/backup-mysql-database-in-xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with a high probability it's going to work. However you should use the export function to save the data to a file. It's more reliable. See comment made by @Moab.

I have tried this some time ago and I got it to work, but I can't remember anymore exactly what files I copied.